# In C++ string, why after the last character, behavior is different when accessed by index and at()?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
string ss("test");
cout << ss[ss.size()] ;
```

Output is null , program terminates normally  but when run this program with at()

```
string ss("test");
cout << ss.at(ss.size()) ;
```

throws an exception . My question is , shouldn't both behavior be the same either both( accessing by index and at())  give abnormal termination or exit normally?

Comment: `at` specifically has error handling for ensuring the index is in range, whereas `operator[]` does not. Note you are likely using `sizeof` wrong, why not test with values such as `0`, `3` and `4` where it might become apparent

Comment: Why do you think `sizeof` on a `std::string` has anything to do with how many characters are held in it?

Comment: *I think this is the right behavior* -- There is no "right behavior".  Second, read the documentation for the [at() function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at).

Comment: Also, a thrown exception is **not** an abnormal termination.  A thrown exception indicates that the underlying C++ library code detected the problem, and actually uses the `throw` keyword to inform the caller of the error.   This is not a "segmentation fault" or "access violation" type error that the OS detects.

Comment: @phuclv This question is specifically about the behavior of `s[s.size()]` and `s.at(s.size())` which involves difference between standards.  That question doesn't seem to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't both behavior be the same either both( accessing by index and at()) give abnormal termination or exit normally?

No, they should not have the same behaviour. The behaviour is different intentionally. If it wasn't, then there would only be a need for one of them to exist.

The `at` member function performs bounds checks. Any access outside the bounds of the container results in an exception. This is the same as the `at` member function of `std::array` or `std::vector` for example. Note that an uncaught throw will cause the program to be terminated.

The subscript operator does not perform any out of bounds checks. Prior to C++11, any access to elements at indices `> size()` has undefined behaviour. Under no circumstance is the subscript operator guaranteed to throw an exception. This is the same as subscript operator of an array, `std::array` or `std::vector` for example.

Since C++11, the behaviour of the subscript operator of `std::string` was changed such that reading the element at index `== size()` (i.e. one past the last element) is well defined, and returns a null terminator. Only modifying the object through the returned reference has undefined behaviour. Reading other indices outside the bounds still has undefined behaviour.

I do not know for a fact the rationale for not making corresponding change to `at` to allow access to the null terminator, but I suspect that it was considered to be a backwards incompatible change. Making UB well defined is always backwards compatible, while ceasing exception throwing is not. Another possible reason is that it would have opened a route to UB (if the null terminator is modified), and the design of `at` is to keep it free from UB.

Answer (score 0):

1. `operator[]` does not check whether the index is valid, and invokes undefined behaviour when the index is out of range. Important the last character is valid('\0') when you use `operator[]`, `ss[ss.size()] = ss[4] = '\0'`. So output is null, program terminates normally. Please try `cout << ss[ss.size() + 1]`, you will get the error.
2. `ss.at(ss.size())`: the last character('\0') InvalidPassing an invalid index (less than 0 
   or greater than or equal to size()) throws an `out_of_range` exception: :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-at-in-cpp/

Comment: `ss[ss.size()` refers to the char just past the end of the string. In all implementations I'm aware of this is a `\0` but there is no guarantee of this. Formally, it's UB.

Comment: @doug Reading `ss[ss.size()]` is formally well defined since C++11.

Comment: @bruce_zhu `please try cout << ss[ss.size() + 1],you will get the error.` There is no guarantee for there to be an error. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: `an invalid index (less than 0 or ...` the index is unsigned, so it is impossible to pass a negative index.

Comment: when using operator[](std::basic_string::reference std::basic_string::operator[](size_type pos);) to get characters in std::string , the range of pos is form 0 to size().Where 0 to size()-1 are the stored characters, and for pos == size() there are the following:
If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned. For the first (non-const) version, the behavior is undefined if this character is modified.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks. Hadn't been aware this had been done formally back in C++11.